# Is there a way to get an arraylist element by its name?

Tags: java, arraylist

I write a program in Java, and i have the following problem:

```
//this is the important part of my class student
public class Student{
    private String name;
    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Getter
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

//this is the other class (could be the main for example)
public class Load {
    private ArrayList<Student> student= new ArrayList<Student>();
    student.add(new Student(name));
}
```

Later in the program I need those students again. I can get them like this:

```
System.out.println(student.get(0));
```

But I dont have the number of the students. Is there a way to get them by the name, which is in the class Student?

Comment: iterate through your list, check if student.getName() equals your search and return if it does. Since Names aren't necessarily unique you might want to return a List<Student>

Comment: you can check if name present in list, student.contains("dfighter3")

Comment: `student.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("name")).findAny().orElse(null)`

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map<String, Student>` (or better a Guava `Multimap<String, Student>` to support multiple students with the same name)  instead?

Comment: the names are unique in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a function which takes a `String` as input, searches the `student` list and returns if the object was found.

```
public Student findStudentByName(String name) {
    for(Student studentObj : student) {
        if(studentObj.getName().equals(name)) {
            return studentObj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case maybe you can use a Map to save that list of Students. Then you shoud get Students by name.

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
Student maryIn = new Student();
maryIn.setName("Mary");
students.put(maryIn.getName(), maryIn);

Student maryOut = students.get("Mary");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of elements in a `list` by using `student.size()`.
Additionally, you should use interface type whenever possible, in your case `List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();`.

Also, have a typo in your code: `student.add(new Student(name));`.

As for the last question, just use an extra method inside `Load` that searches for the desired student name in the current list:

```
public Student searchByName(String targetStudentName) {
    for (Student s : student) {
        if (targetStudentName.equals(s.getName())) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```